# What javascript min tool does jquery use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I have a great deal of javascript that needs to be min'd before being served to the end user.  Currently, I'm using JSMIN, but I'd like to switch to something a bit more powerful (such as something with local variable replacement).  I'm currently looking at YUI min developed by yahoo, and it got me thinking about the min tool that jquery uses.  Does anyone know what it is and if it's publicly available?  Also, any recommendations on other min tools that might be better suited than YUI min?  If possible, I'd like a java solution so I can just plug the library into what I've already created for the JSMIN solution.

Thanks

Comment: EDIT: I took a closer look at the frequently asked questions on the jquery website, and it looks like they use the YUI Compressor.  Still, any other suggestions are welcome - I want to get this right.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question so you can accept it.

Comment: Seems that they now recommend YUI, but they utilize(d) JSMIN.

http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/build/js/jsmin.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4, [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) is used.

See the [FAQ in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_compress_my_code.3F).

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked/answered, jQuery has switched over to an entirely JavaScript-based build system. Their minification is done using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) now, which runs in NodeJS.

Comment: See [jQuery Blog » Help Us Money-ify UglifyJS 2.0 (2012-09-06)](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/06/help-us-money-ify-uglifyjs-2-0/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice one that will do CSS as well.

http://jawr.java.net/

Comment: Updated link to their migrated site.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [build folder in the trunk](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/build) you can see they've been using [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) since Jan. 09

Comment: You can see the log message from Resig himself: http://dev.jquery.com/log/trunk/jquery/build/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar?rev=6123